# Active class not working with li on bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to change the `background-color` of the active `li` in a navbar. Its very strange that just the `background-color` attribute is not working.
Here's my code
Html:

```html
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    @Html.ActionLink("Expand", "Index", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand hidden-md hidden-lg" })
  </div>
  <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      @{string actionName = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString();}
      <li class="@((actionName=="Index")?"active":"")"> @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
      <li class="@((actionName=="Destinations"||actionName=="Attractions")?"active":"") dropdown" role="presentation">
        <a class="dropbtn" id="dropdownMenu1" href="#">Destinations</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          @Html.ActionLink("Attractions", "Attractions", "Home", null, new { @class = "link" })
          @Html.ActionLink("Popular Destinations", "Destinations", "Home", null, new { @class = "link" })
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="@((actionName=="Seasons")?"active":"")">@Html.ActionLink("Seasons", "Seasons", "Home")</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Css

```css
#navbarCollapse {
  background-color:#1dbbd3;
}

#navbarCollapse ul li.active {
  border:1px solid red;
  background-color:#7b278e;
  color:#f2f2f2;
}

#navbarCollapse li a {
  color:#f2f2f2;
}

#navbarCollapse li a:hover {
  background-color:#7b278e;
  color:#f2f2f2;
  font-weight:600;
}
```

Its really strange that just the `background-color` is not working. Even the `border:1px solid red` is working!. Please help

Comment: Maybe some other CSS code is overriding it ?

Comment: Make sure `#navbarCollapse ul li.active ` is not overridden. inspect the elements and check it out

Answer (score 0):

I tested your markup and CSS and found following CSS rule overriding your `background-color`: `.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a` with `background-color: #e7e7e7;`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes.. That was it.